# why we need to serialize and deserialize

Tags: json, deserialize, serialize

why we need to serialize and deserialize? Why don't we save the value directly into database with out serialize. What is the benefit for doing serialize. I know that by doing serialize it will get converted into JSON form but need to know why to serialize is there any advantage for doing it. Please guide.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask. Are you able to describe a situation where you think serialization/deserialization is unnecessary?

Comment: Is your question about a specific scenario ? Currently it's unclear whether you're asking about serialization in a general way or specific to a single scenario. Serialization is usually done so that objects in memory can be communicated to other systems.

Comment: Anu, know that the above comments are trying to help you improve your question. By asking clear and specific questions you help us help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you didn't serialize the object into JSON, then the object would not be in a format that the consumer (the system who did the request) would understand. The purpose of serializing it into JSON is so that the message will be a format that can be understood and from there, deserialize it into an object type that makes sense for the consumer.